# Pythonic way to use enum arguments - avoid import clutter

Tags: python, enums

I have a function in `module_a` which has two behaviors depending on a user selected option. The option has a string-type representation. Since it's easy for users to mistype strings* I've chosen to use an enum as the input to the function to specify the option.

```
# module_a.py

from enum import Enum

class FooOptions(Enum):
    option_a = 'option_a'
    option_b = 'option_b'

def foo(x, option=FooOptions.option_a):
    if option == FooOptions.option_a:
        print('running option_a')
        y = x * 2
    elif option == FooOptions.option_b:
        print('running option_b')
        y = x**2
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(f'option \'{option}\' not implemented. '
                                  f'option must be {FooOptions.option_a} or {FooOptions.option_b}.')
```

I want to use `foo()` in `module_b` but it seems like a pain to have to import the enum class as well just to use `foo()`. Of course the user could

```
# module_b.py

from module_b import foo, FooOptions

x = 42
y1 = foo(x, option=FooOptions.option_a)
y2 = foo(x, option=FooOptions.option_b)

print(x)
print(y1)
print(y2)
```

Is this the best way to handle this even though `FooOptions` is ONLY USED with the single method `foo()`? Of course the user could explicitly pass `option=option_a` or similar but then the typo possibility is more likely. What is a good way to handle this?

*Capitalization issues can be handled by converting an inputs to lower case, for example. However, a user might easily use - instead of _ or vice-versa. Or simple typos are possible.

Comment: There's really nothing wrong with `import module_b` then `module_b.foo(x, option=module_b.FooOptions.option_a)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Nothing wrong, no; horribly verbose, yes.  The problem I have with horribly verbose code is not skipping the important parts while trying to ignore the boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance I think the best use of enums would be:

```
__all__ = ['foo', 'OPTION_A', 'OPTION_B']

class FooOptions(Enum):
    OPTION_A = 'option_a'
    OPTION_B = 'option_b'
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<%s.%s>" % (self.__class__.__name__, self._name_)
OPTION_A, OPTION_B = FooOptions
```

Then in module b:

```
from module_a import foo, OPTION_A, OPTION_B

foo(x, OPTION_B)
```

and if you are debugging and in `foo` do something like:

```
    print(f"{option=}")  # I think that's the shortcut for printing a repr in a format string
```

you'll get

```
option=<FooOptions.OPTION_B>  # for example
```

Comment: I don't think `__all__ = ['foo', 'OPTION_A', 'OPTION_B']` is required

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: It's not required, but it's good practice to put your public API in `__all__`, even if you don't use/recommend `from ... import *`.